# Can Azure Functions be deployed to IIS?

Tags: azure, iis, azure-functions

I've been trying out Azure Functions and have deployed them successfully to Azure. As their name suggests, Azure Functions are intended to be deployed to Azure. However, now I have the need to deploy those functions to local IIS.
I'm aware that I can adapt the code and create a regular WebAPI project instead, but was wondering if the Azure Function project can be deployed to IIS as-is or with minimal changes.
In Visual Studio there doesn't seem to be an option to publish to local IIS. I tried the option to publish to a Folder (bin/Release). I tried to deploy those files to IIS but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I just answered another similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63516086/6732525

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to run Functions on your own infrastructure, you should use [Azure Functions Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-runtime-overview).

It is deployed to Windows Containers (not IIS), but it will give you a similar experience to Azure-hosted Function Apps.

Comment: For future readers, the link should be changed to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/hybrid/azure-functions-hybrid#running-azure-functions-on-premises