# How can I get function invocations to show in the console output from the Azure Functions host?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I'm not able to use Azure in my organisation, so I've installed the [Azure Functions host](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host) on an on-prem server. Everything is running as expected, except for the logs. Steps to reproduce:

1. Install the [Asp.Net Core 6.0 hosting bundle](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-6.0.11-windows-hosting-bundle-installer)
2. Extract the [Azure Functions host](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/releases) into `C:\inetpub\Functions.X.X.X`
3. Update the 'authentication' section of `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` to allow overrides
4. Publish the function app to a folder
5. Add a 'Logs' folder and give the user 'IIS_IUSRS' full permission on the logs folder
6. Add the following 'web.config' to the folder

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore" />
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore
        processPath="C:\inetpub\Functions.4.14.0\4.14.0\64bit\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.exe"
        stdoutLogEnabled="true"
        stdoutLogFile=".\Logs\stdout"
        hostingModel="InProcess">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="AzureWebJobsStorage" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
        <environmentVariable name="FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME" value="dotnet" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The script host is using the following `host.json` settings:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "tracing": {
        "consoleLevel": "verbose"
    },
    "logging": {
        "fileLoggingMode": "always",
        "logLevel": {
            "default": "Information"
        }
    }
}
```

I expected the output in this file to look similar to what is shown when debugging locally:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:7201
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5201
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Repositories\iPM Web API\src\WaikatoDhb.Ipm.Api\
```

However, what I see is this:

```
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FunctionApp1
Now listening on: http://*:40020/
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

It seems like a simplified version of the logs, and **I cannot see function invocations** in this output. This is crucial for investigating unexpected behaviour, or identifying failures in upstream dependencies. What am I missing here? How can I get function invocations to show in the console output from the Azure Functions host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue; however, I was running the Azure Function Host in a Docker container. The following environment variable enables logging the Function invocations (and much more depending on the configured logL level) to console:

```
AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true
```

Comment: Good find, this pointed me to the [logging.console section of the host.json file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#console) which looks like exactly what I was missing

Answer (score 0):

> **I cannot see function invocations** in this output.

AFAIK, When the Azure Functions (of any stack like Java, C#, etc.) running locally, you can see the Function invocation logs in the path of `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\LogFiles\Application\Functions`

[image]

All the verbose level information and debug level logs can be stored in this path `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\LogFiles\Application\Functions\Host`:

[image]

Comment: The Azure Functions Host is running in IIS, not on my user account. I can't see a folder starting with 'IIS' or 'IUSR' in 'C:\Users'. What would this folder be mapped to?

Comment: Azure Functions will use its runtime on local environment on windows containers not the IIS. I haven't found any article or official doc to host in IIS. Please check this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45460402) regarding on-premises running of Azure Functions and provide the details such as code, how you deployed (steps) to IIS (clearly) in a new question so that it will be visible to all the community members, will assist better.

Comment: I've updated the question with very clear steps to reproduce the issue. It's worth mentioning I'd much rather use Docker if I could. I'm doing this as a last resort, because all the normal options are not available